# Format string from ISO-8601 date with original timezone in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, formatting

I have a ISO8601 string with some arbitrary time zone. I **don't** want to convert to my time zone. Rather, I want to preserve the original time zone. I want to be able to format the output similar to how *gmdate* formats the date/time. For example:

```
$output =  my_date_function( 'F d, ga', $thetime );
```

Should output:

```
$thetime = '2012-09-24T21:00:00-0700';
     => September 24, 9pm

$thetime = '2012-09-24T21:00:00-0500';
     => September 24, 9pm
```

Comment: Just speculating, but what if you sliced off the last 5 characters of `$thetime` or replaced them with `+0000`?

Comment: `+0000` would not necessarily be my server's timezone.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would work but I think that DateTime::createFromFormat can do it automatically. You can also create a function that determine the timezone and create a DateTimezone object with it.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
According to the documentation :

> If timezone is omitted ***and time contains no timezone***, the current timezone will be used

*Code:*

```
$stime = '2012-09-24T21:00:00-0500';
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, substr($stime, 0, 19));
$output = $t->format('F d, ga');
```

Comment: I tried the constant `DateTime::ISO8601`, but it did not work for me. The hard-coded string does work.